# Mortarboard badges

Tags: support, badges

In reference to its [definition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard), the Mortarboard badge is offered if at least 200 reputation is earned in a single day.

I received 212 reputation yesterday and haven't received any badge. Is it a bug or is there something I misunderstood about the badge?

Comment: I made a search by the word "motarboard" before asking the question and didn't receive any result. try it! even when writing the title, meta should match it to other similar titles but didn't quote any!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gjOzU.png

Comment: probably the spelling: If you search for `Motarboard`, you are missing an `r`. I submitted an edit to fix the title of this question where the same `r` is missing as well.

Comment: @AndersUP I wasn't sure if the spelling was the problem or not; OP got it right in the post body **(?)**.

Comment: Yeah you right, I wrote motarboard.. sorry

Comment: I thought 200 was the max rep you could earn in a day (barring account association)?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Bounties and accepts count after the cap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The association bonus is not taken into account for the Mortarboard badge.

Without the bonus, you earned 112 points, not enough for the badge.

Quoting from the [full list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67402):

> - Reputation points earned for associating accounts do not count for the badge